# Building AWS Infrastructure - Security Questions

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, cloud, vpc

I am building an cloud infrastructure on AWS.
I have some backend applications (like database servers) and other front end app (like webservers) that needs ingoing/outgoing traffic.

I also have some devops/dev app  like Jenkins, and Airlfow (a workflow management tahts has a web UI) that i need to protect. Some of these apps, like Airflow, doesn't have security mechanism (for example login/password). And I still need access it on 80 port from Internet.

I was thinking to setup a AWS VPC, with a private subnet and public subnet. In the public subnet I will put the fron end apps and the private subnet I will put the backend services (like databases).

1. For the backend services, I need a way to my dev team to connect, for example, in a MySQL database (port: 3306).

   - What is the correct way of do this?
   - I need to expose port 3306?
   - Do I need a NAT or a bastion host? What is the difference between them?
   - If I setup a NAT/Bastion hosti will make a port foward rigth? If I have two instances of a mysql database, how can I connect to each other using the bastion? I  need to allocate different ports on bastion and make the port foward?
2. For the devops/dev app:

   - Which subnet do I choose?
   - If i put on the private subnet, how can my team access it on 80 port?
   - Do i need a intranet/vpc foo this applications?

Answer (score 2):

These are all quite common problems people are faced with on AWS. You have lots of options.

You could put all of your backend and dev opps services in the private subnet. You then have a number of choices to connect to them securely.

**Option 1**

Use [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) to limit access to these nodes. You can use Security groups to only allow specific IP addresses to connect to your resources.

**Option 2**

Use a bastion host.

Referring to your question "What is the difference NAT and bastion host?".

NAT simply allows instance inside a private subnet to connect to the internet by routing all their traffic through the NAT instance. The NAT instance then directs the return traffic from the internet back to the correct nodes in the private subnet. NAT alone does not allow you to connect to instances inside your private subnet from the outside, you'd need to combine it with Port Address Translation to achieve this.

A Bastion host is an instance that you place in a public subnet of your VPC. You can therefore connect to it from the internet. Once you're connected to your Bastion host, you can connect to any other instance inside your VPC using the private IP. Once you ensure maximum security to your bastion host, you're in business.

As a result, you could use a bastion host to connect to all those special nodes in your private subnet.

**Option 3**

Set up a [VPN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html) connection to your VPC using the built in functionality in VPC or setting up a VPN instance with something like OpenSwan running on it.

VPN connections are extremely secure but can often be a tad temperamental (*personal opinion from personal experience).

So,  you have lots of choices. I'd recommend doing a few more google searches and digging deeper into the AWS docs as these are all commonly asked questions!

Good luck! :)